# Редактирование шрифта Raleway(кириллический) через Панель Администратора Wordpress/

Tags: wordpress, шрифты, google-fonts

Подключил шрифт Ralewey кириллический,отображается все если классу присвоить font-family: 'RalewayExtraBold' !important; .Нужно сделать так ,чтобы я мог редактировать шрифт через Панель Администратора ,в любом тексте.Чтобы там можно было выбрать размер шрифта.

Чтобы вот тут была кнопка Семейство шрифтов  и можно было выбрать нужный мне шрифт и нужный размер шрифта - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это не админка WordPress, а интерфейс плагина Visual Composer. Сделать вот прямо кнопку в Текстовом блоке проблематично. Но можно переключиться в текстовый режим и обернуть ваш текст в <p style="font-family: RalewayExtraBold;">...</p>

Comment: А еще проще -задать класс текстовому блоку (такая возможность есть в настройках) и в style.css прописать стили для этого класса.

Comment: Кнопку я добавил,теперь как добавить этот шрифт в список шрифтов,смотрите картинку сверху.